# 2d Game Physics Ease In / Out Based on Velocity

Tags: math, user-interface, 2d, physics, cocos2d-x

I've recently been experimenting and attempting to recreate an iOS UI sort of edge bouncing effect in my game so that if you scroll past a level's boundaries, the camera slowly bounces back to the boundary.

At the moment I've implemented some of Robert Penner's tweening calculations ported from ActionScript, however I'm unsure whether this is the correct approach due to the fact that it doesn't take into account our camera's velocity. At the moment it looks something like this:

`easeInOut(currentTime, startValue, endValue, duration);`

The actual implementations are available here: http://www.jesusgollonet.com/blog/2007/09/24/penner-easing-cpp/

I've come to the conclusion that this is a sort of grey area as I haven't been able to find much information on it, either that or I'm not familiar with the correct name for the sort of calculation I'm attempting to describe. If anyone has any advice on using velocity in an easing in/out calculation in a 2d game or UI, I'd be very interested to hear it!

Comment: This question may be more suitable on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This has been asked a number of times before.  One simple way would be using a [sigmoid curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).  Another way would be to have an acceleration vector in the direction of movement, which switches direction when the object/camera is halfway to its final position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [critically damped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Critical_damping_.28.CE.B6_.3D_1.29) spring between the edge and and the camera. You force would be F=-w*w*x - 2*w*v where w is the spring's natural frequency (try a few different values until you get something you like) x is the displacement from the boundary and v is the current speed.

Comment: This worked like an absolute charm and was exactly what was needed. Thanks to your input I've also searched out additional material on similar topics.

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d (and -x) have CCEaseIn and CCEaseOut, [among many others](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d0/d79/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_action_ease.html).

You create these with a time parameter, so could you not just scale the time based on your camera velocity? The faster it moves, the quicker it "bounces" back with a shorter time given to the ease action. I wouldn't have used any fancy tweening implementations for this, as cocos2d has many easing actions already available.

Comment: The camera movement is not implemented using cocos2d's action system, I doubt this would be a viable solution.